# Erro ao inserir formula em uma célula no Excel via C#? Worksheet?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
newWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Status";
var var1 = newWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] as Excel.Range;
var1.Formula = "=CONT.SE(Planilha1!B2:B7;'Ativo')";
newWorksheet.Cells[3, 1] = "=CONT.SE(Planilha1!B2:B7;'Bloqueado";
```

A Primeira célula, "Status" não dá erro.
Porém a partir da segunda, nesta linha:

`var1.Formula = "=CONT.SE(Planilha1!B2:B7;'Ativo')";`

dá o erro:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exceção de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'
```

Podem, me ajudar?

Estou usando a biblioteca: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Quando insere desta forma:

```
            newWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Status";
            newWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Formula = 
                "CONT.SE(Planilha1!B2:B7;\"Ativo\")";
```

O Texto é inserido na célula. Porém, preciso dele como fórmula, ou seja, o o "=" antes do texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a solução. 
O Excel lê as fórmulas em Inglês;
Porém, o Excel na máquina, é Português;
Então, foi definido que o mesmo deveria ler em Inglês:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
                 new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Assim, a fórmula foi inserida também em inglês:

```
            newWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Formula = "=COUNTIF(Planilha1!B2:B7,\"Ativo\")";
            newWorksheet.Cells[3, 1].Formula = "=COUNTIF(Planilha1!B2:B7,\"Bloqueado\")";
```

Comment: by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033148/excelcom-writing-formula-into-cell-results-in-name

Answer (score 0):

> newWorksheet.Cells[3, 1] = "=CONT.SE(Planilha1!B2:B7;'Bloqueado";

Está faltando fechar parenteses na fórmula `=CONT.SE()`.

Comment: Boa observação. Porém o erro dá em uma linha acima. srsrsrsrs.

Answer (score -4):

Testando descobrir que o excel para não da erro #NOME? voce deve inserir a celular em ingles

```
 public void formulaInExcel(string range1, string range2, string formula)
        {
             _Excel.Range cellRange = ws.Range[$"{range1}:{range2}"];
            cellRange.Formula = $"=sum(A1:A1)";
        }
```

Ai o proprio excel faz a converção para =soma()